# Can Dynamic Distribution List detect and add a user with a certain email alias?

Tags: email

I want to know if anyone has done this before.

DDL has this condition: All email addresses containing @sample.com can be a member of this DDL.

Now, they have a user who has @testing.com that cannot get into the DDL despite having an alias of @sample.com.

Beside changing the primary email of the user, is there any workaround to this?